# Fortran LAPACK cblat1 check2 ctest: pass value instead of array?

Tags: arrays, fortran, lapack

I'm porting LAPACK over to Jai, and I stumbled upon the following strange code:
In [LAPACK/cblat1/check2](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d0/d78/cblat1_8f_a9ff9298afee60deb7ffaea43a6d1b668.html#a9ff9298afee60deb7ffaea43a6d1b668), line 569

```
CALL ctest(leny,cy,ct8(1,kn,ki),csize2(1,ksize),sfac)
```

`ctest` is called with an array `cy(7)`, but the next argument `ct8(1,kn,ki)` is just a number. However, `ctest` requires arrays of the same size:

```
SUBROUTINE ctest(LEN,CCOMP,CTRUE,CSIZE,SFAC)
 *     **************************** CTEST *****************************
 *
 *     C.L. LAWSON, JPL, 1978 DEC 6
 *
 *     .. Scalar Arguments ..
       REAL             SFAC
       INTEGER          LEN
 *     .. Array Arguments ..
       COMPLEX          CCOMP(LEN), CSIZE(LEN), CTRUE(LEN)
...
```

What is happening here? Is `ct8(1,kn,ki)` implicitly converted to an array of size 7 with the value `ct8(1,kn,ki)` in all fields?

Comment: The linked question and its answers explain that when you have `ct8(1,kn,ki)` as the actual argument, that element _and the following `len-1` elements_ are associated with the array dummy argument. The key term is "sequence association" and you can find other cases with that.